# 403 error when posting to group using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, http-status-code-403, facebook-group

I am trying to use the facebook graph API to post to a facebook group that I am the admin of.When I make the POST request,I am getting a 403 access denied error. This indicates some problem with authentication, I believe.  I have made sure my user token is valid and that I am asking for the correct permissions.  Here is my code handling the request and handling the user permissions:

Request:

```
$.ajax({url: `https://graph.facebook.com/766394103749626/feed?message=This%is%my%message&link=https://google.com/&access_token=ValidAccessToken`,
        method: "POST"})
```

Permissions
**user_friends, user_posts, groups_access_member_info, publish_to_groups**

Comment: you should encode all get parameters. why not use the js sdk? much easier to handle. i would not even use jquery for a simple ajax call, there is the native fetch api or axios, for example. but that´s just a side note.

Comment: The response body should contain more information about the error.

Comment: The request did not return a response.

Comment: You are 100% sure? How are you checking the response body?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  I am console logging the response as soon as it comes back and the console log never runs.